# kotlin-android-extensions in ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, adapter, kotlin-android-extensions

```
class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

       fun bindata(text: SingleText){
            itemView.title.text = text.title
            itemView.desc.text = text.desc
       }
}
```

like this code, Kotlin has any cache in android-extensions?

when i decompile kotlin bytecode

```
public final void bindata(@NotNull SingleText text) {

  Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(text, "text");
  ((AppCompatTextView)this.itemView.findViewById(id.title)).setText((CharSequence)text.getTitle());
  ((AppCompatTextView)this.itemView.findViewById(id.desc)).setText((CharSequence)text.getDesc());

}
```

it means when i called binData in Adapter.onBindViewHolder(), it will called findViewById each time

This significantly increases the loss of performance，and It does not achieve the purpose of layout reuse

Kotlin has any cache logic in android-extensions with ViewHolder?

Comment: `findViewById` finds already created view. So that means you are reusing it. There is no performance issue that your are talking about.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

View caching in a `ViewHolder` or any custom class is possible only from [Kotlin 1.1.4](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/08/kotlin-1-1-4-is-out/) and it's currently in the experimental stage.

1. Update your Kotlin version in your root level build.gradle file

`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.4-3"`

2. Add these lines in your app `build.gradle`:

`androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}`

3. Inherit your `ViewHolder` class from `LayoutContainer`. `LayoutContainer` is an interface available in `kotlinx.android.extensions` package.
4. Add the below imports, where `view_item` is the layout name.

`import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.view_item.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.view_item.view.*`

The entire `ViewHolder` class looks like:

```
class ViewHolder(override val containerView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView),
        LayoutContainer {

    fun bind(title: String) {
        itemTitle.text = "Hello Kotlin!" // itemTitle is the id of the TextView in the layout 
    }
}
```

The decompiled Java code shows that this class uses cache for the Views:

```
    public final void bind(@NotNull String title) {
          Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(title, "title");
          ((TextView)this._$_findCachedViewById(id.itemTitle)).setText((CharSequence)"Hello Kotlin!");
    }
```

Further readings: [KEEP proposal](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/android-extensions-entity-caching.md), [an awesome tutorial](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/).

Answer (score 13):

From my understanding, kotlin-android-extensions is just a statically imported extension(generated codes) to replace View.findViewById.

I would recommend you to store the references in your view holder.

```
class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
   val title: TextView = itemView.title
   val desc: TextView = itemView.desc

   fun bindata(text: SingleText){
       title.text = text.title
       desc.text = text.desc
   }
}
```

One of the benefits of this approach is any type mismatch will be discovered in compile time!

Comment: If you add a line of code for each View, you might as well not use Kotlin Android extensions. If you wrap findViewById() in an extension function it will be type safe as well. `val title = itemView.find<TextView>(R.id.title)`

Comment: @FrankHarper if `R.id.title` is not pointing to a TextView, let say pointed to ImageView. `itemView.find<TextView>(R.id.title)` will still compile and will cause run-time crash while using Kotlin Android extensions will throw error at compile time.

Answer (score -1):

In your project gradle:-

```
 buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
```

and in your app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {}
dependencies {
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

After these you can use in you activity :

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.unit_preferences_activity.*
```

and:

```
  private fun setClickListener() {
            rlCaloriesBurnt.setOnClickListener{
                launchActivity(CaloriesBurntPrefreenceUnit::class.java)
            }

            rlDistanceTravelled.setOnClickListener{

           tvDistanceUnit.text=resources.getString(R.string.km)

                launchActivity(DistanceTravelledUnit::class.java)
            }

            rlWaterConsumption.setOnClickListener{
                launchActivity(WaterPreferenceUnit::class.java)
            }
            backArrow.setOnClickListener{
                finish()
            }

        }
```